# How to localize the reply header in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

When replying in German I want to have the standard opening line

> Am XX.XX.XXX um 21:22 schrieb Nobody's Perfect:

But if I reply in English the German opening is awkward and I want to see:

> On XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX, Nobody's Perfect wrote:

I can achieve this by changing the Thunderbird language and restarting Thunderbird. But this can't be the solution because I often write in different languages. What I need is a way to change the language depending on the recipient(s).

There are Thunderbird extensions like [ReplyWithHeader](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/replywithheader/) or [ChangeQuoteAndReplyFormat](https://freeshell.de//%7Ekaosmos/changequote-en.html). But these extensions introduce an Outlook style header and don't solve the localization question.

Is there a way switch the **message** language without restarting the application? Is is possible to configure the reply language based on a configuration in the address book or any configuration file to get an individual opening line?